# React Router Link not redirecting on enter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to build a simple news app as practice. I am using the NewsApi for all the data.

Im hitting their "search" end point and everything works when I click on the link, but when I hit enter i get " Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `to` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`." and it hits the endpoint with whatever the last search topic was. i.e search for yankees and click link, it works but then I type in dodgers and hit enter and it goes to "/yankees?"

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Search = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  let history = useHistory()
  const handleEnter = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode == "Enter") {
      history.push(`/${e}`);
    } else {
      setInput(e);
    }
  };
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        onChange={(e) => handleEnter(e.target.value)}
      />

      <Link to={input}>Search</Link>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

I was able to get it to work like this

```
const Search = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  let history = useHistory();
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        onChange={(e) => {
          setInput(e.target.value);
        }}
        onKeyDown={(e) => {
          if (e.code === "Enter") {
            history.push(`/${input}`);
          }
        }}
        placeholder='Search by keyword'
      />
      <Link to={input}>Search</Link>
    </form>
  );
};
```

It now pushes to the correct component on pressing enter, but in the url the the search topic ends with a ? i.e. localhost:3000/mets?, but when clicking on the link the url shows like localhost:3000/mets.

What us the difference, are there likely to be performance issues, and how do i resolve them?

Comment: try changing the state var name from `input` to something else like `_input`.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you give *input* a default value, it should fix the warning. You just can't have *undefined* as the default value.

```
const [input, setInput] = useState('/');
```

Comment: it works when I click on the link, but when I hit enter it goes to the previous search topic.

Answer (score 0):

When you are handing `Enter` key down event, you shouldn't be using `onChange`. You should handle it as `onKeyDown` event. In the handler check for enter keycode and input value set in state then use `Redirect` to route.

`<Redirect to={input}/>`

Not tested, but this is the approach.

Comment: I got it to work using inline function onKeydown, but the url is showing a ? at the end i.e. localhost:3000/searchTopic? what is causing this and how can i fix it?

Comment: Please give more details or update your question so that people look and answer. Hope my answer is useful

Comment: I have edited the original post to show I "fixed" the original issue and hopefully clarify the new issue

Comment: Its better to use `Redirect` than `history.push` as mentioned in the answer. I assume you did not try with `Redirect`